# Append structs to a vector<uint8_t>

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a message comuniction lib, and need to read some data to a struct, and append this struct to a vector, and read again, append again.

If in C language, memcpy works perfect, but I want is to make all code in C++11 code style.

I tried to use std::copy, but it needs a begin and end interator, so how exactly I can use std::copy like `std::copy(&a, &a + sizeof(A), back_inserter(buffer));`?

Comment: Is your struct POD? If not, what you're doing is effectively dangerous by design. I would still use memcpy here, because what you're doing is effectively old-hat C. I would add a static_assert though for safety reasons to ensure that `static_assert(std::is_pod_v<T>, "Must be plain-old data");`

Comment: You would have to cast the pointers to `uint8_t*` to make this work, and even then I'm not sure it would. The best option is to not use a struct as an intermediary.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh the struct is totally POD.

Comment: @reavenisadesk My best advice here is then to use a C-style interface, with C++ safety tacked on. Use memcpy, ensure any multibyte values get converted to a consistent byteorder, and use `reinterpret_cast<void*>`, since what you're doing is effectively just adding stronger guarantees to C code. The `static_assert` ensures that if you ever change your code, you have a compile-time guarantee that you did not introduce dangerous behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
struct MyStruct {
   int a;
   double b;
   int c;
};
std::vector<uint8_t> buffer;
MyStruct data { 42, 3.14159, 123 };
uint8_t* ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&data);
std::copy(ptr, ptr + sizeof(data), back_inserter(buffer));
```

<strike>Note that `std::copy` in this case just reverts to `std::memcpy` underneath</strike>, and `reinterpret_cast` throws away all type safety of the language. Alexander's suggestion of using a `static_assert` is a good one.

**EDIT:**

Mário is right, `back_inserter` would cause `std::copy` to not be equivalent to `std::memcpy`. An alternative could be to reallocate your buffer first, then copy:

```
size_t len = buffer.size();
buffer.resize(len+sizeof(data));
std::copy(ptr, ptr + sizeof(data), buffer.data() + len);
```

(or something to that extent).

Comment: That `back_inserter` can [prevent](https://godbolt.org/g/7ikDBU) some optimizations, not to mention how slow it is. Also, doing `buffer.insert(buffer.end(), ptr, ptr + sizeof(data))` is much better with regard to optimization, as `insert` can `reserve` beforehand. Last nitpick: because `(u)int8_t` is an integer type, it is not safe to assume that reading from a pointer is not UB, albeit I don't know of any implementation that doesn't `typedef char int8_t`. All in all, use `(unsigned) char` or `std::byte` instead.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi what if I use vector.reserve to get a fixed size of memory first? Will the back_inserter still slow?

Comment: @reavenisadesk Measure it! My intuition says it helps, but don't rely on intuitions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clean C++ way to do it:

First a simple range type:

```
template<class It>
struct range_t {
  It b, e;
  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }
  std::size_t size() const { return end()-begin(); }
};

template<class It>
range_t<It> range(It s, It f) { return {s,f}; }
```

it represents a range of some iterators.

Next, some functions to treat pod data as bytes:

```
template<class T>
range_t< unsigned char* > as_bytes( T* t ) {
  static_assert( std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value, "bad idea if not trivially copyable" );
  auto* ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(t);
  return range(ptr, ptr+sizeof(T));
}
template<class T>
range_t< unsigned char const* > as_bytes( T const* t ) {
  static_assert( std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value, "bad idea if not trivially copyable" );
  auto* ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const*>(t);
  return range(ptr, ptr+sizeof(T));
}
```

both read and write versions.

Next, functions that take a structure and stuff them into a vector, or pop them out:

```
template<class T>
void push_bytes_in( std::vector<std::uint8_t>& target, T const* data ) {
  auto bytes = as_bytes(data);
  target.insert( target.end(), bytes.begin(), bytes.end() );
}
template<class T>
bool pop_bytes_out( std::vector<std::uint8_t>& src, T* data ) {
  auto bytes = as_bytes(data);
  if (bytes.size() > src.size()) return false;
  std::copy( src.end()-bytes.size(), src.end(), bytes.begin() );
  src.resize( src.size()-bytes.size() );
  return true;
}
```

Finally, test code:

```
struct some_data {
  int x, y;
  char buff[1024];
};



std::vector<std::uint8_t> bytes;

some_data data{1,2, "hello"};
push_bytes_in( bytes, &data );
some_data d2;
if (!pop_bytes_out( bytes, &d2)) {
    std::cout << "failed\n";
    return -1;
}
std::cout << d2.buff << "\n";
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/JcyXzP).

We could optimize push bytes if they turn out to be too slow to pre-size the buffer, then shove the bytes in using std copy or memcpy.  However, you should be careful to ensure exponential data reservation in that case.

```
template<class T>
void push_bytes_in( std::vector<std::uint8_t>& target, T const* data ) {
  if (target.capacity() < target.size()+sizeof(T)) {
    target.reserve( target.capacity()*3/2 +1 );
  }
  auto bytes = as_bytes(data);
  target.resize( target.size() + sizeof(T) );
  std::copy( bytes.begin(), bytes.end(), target.end()-sizeof(T) );
}
```

that may turn out to be a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vector insert member function.

This is better than copy since vector insert knows how to allocate memory(you do not need to use ugly back_inserter).

```
void append(std::vector<unsigned char>& v, const MyStruct& s){
    v.insert(v.end(), (unsigned char*) &s, ((unsigned char*)&s)+sizeof s);   
}
```

full code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c1ee0d09d4de64e)

note that this is very simple code compared to Yakk answer but I think it may be easier for some people to read code without templates. Also I use C style cast that some people think should not be done in C++ but I find reinterpret cast too verbose for this use case.

Comment: I wrote a test code like `auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(a_ptr->data);
    vec.insert(vec.end(), ptr, ptr + a_ptr->len);` and it works fine in http://cpp.sh/, but when I use it in my code, compiler throw errors:  no matching member function for call to 'insert'. I look up the standard interface for insert, and did not find so defination like this, is this a standard c++ vector interface?

Comment: Pointers are iterators. So it is overload (4) on this link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert   Also my answer has full code here part where you can find compilable example